# How to remove glitchy color transitions?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am in the process of designing an animated menu. I tried to get the text in the boxes to change color and they do so, but it's rather glitchy. The text flashes after the transition, and when you hover over it. Here's the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Imagifight/1g91baxu/) with the glitch.
I also noticed it works fine without the hover transition, except of course the text doesn't change color. Here's that one: [Less glitchy one](https://jsfiddle.net/Imagifight/mgsc3gpn/).

Please suggest a fix.

Glitchy code [I removed webkit]

```css
/* CSS */
@keyframes box {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    width: 30px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 30px;
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 30px;
    width: 70px;
    color: #FFF;
  }
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  color: cyan;
  font-family: 'Agency FB';
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: cyan;
  color: transparent;
  animation: box 1.0s forwards;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
 div:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}
div:hover label {
  color: cyan;
}
label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  font-family: 'Agency FB';
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<h1>
Test
</h1>
<div id="1">
  <label>Hello</label>
</div>
<br>
<div id="1">
  <label>World</label>
</div>
<br>
<div id="1">
  <label>Foobar</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the glitch, but probably is because of this:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

maybe you have other color fot the text in the parent, if you only want the transition on the background-color useit only there

```
transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
```

andto avoid the change of height you can use this

```
 box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you mean by "glitchy".
First of all I would change:

```
border: 1px solid cyan;
```

To:

```
outline: 1px solid cyan;
```

Border made this div move a little bit when hover works.